# Default Selected item in select list Using TbActiveForm

Tags: php, yii

I am using TbActiveForm. I want to display default selected item in select list Please help me, My code as follows,

```
<?php 
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'type', CHtml::listData(MyModel::model()->findAll(),'id','name');, array('class'=>'span5', 'maxlength'=>255)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default which value you want to select set that value in options array

```
<?php 
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'column_name',$list,array('empty'=>'--Select--','options'=>array('value'=>array('selected'=>true)))); ?>
?>
```

Comment: Where to set value in option array.

Comment: under 'value' put your default selected value 'options'=>array('default_value'=>array('selected'=>true))